# A rotation of 30 degree

Tags: angle

What does it mean if an object moves 30 degree ? What will be its position now ? ( The concept of angles looks abstract to me. I cannot visualise it.)

Thanks!

Comment: It does not have a meaning by `move 30 degree`, you should provide the center of rotation.

Comment: Please explain everything to me! I know nothing. What do you mean by "center of rotaion". Initially, there was just an object which moved that many degrees. Where did this center of rotation come from ?

Comment: You'll need to provide the context for "an object moved $30$ degrees."  Where did you see this?  It could mean any number of things depending on the context.

Comment: I suggest this video for very basic knowledge: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJTxv-tRKj0

Comment: Suppose I am looking at an object and then someone puts the object at some other place. And now he says now I have rotated it at 30° degree. What does this whole excerise mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Draw a circle and trace it with a pencil counter-clockwise.

Every time that you trace the whole circle you have rotated your starting point $360$ degrees.

If you only go  a quarter circle then you have rotated $90$ degrees.

For a $30$ degree rotation you have to only rotate a third of a quarter around.

Remember a whole turn around a point is $360$ degrees.

Comment: In my books, I come arcoss angles which are more than 360° such as ,  1800°, 720°, 1440°, 2160°, 2520°, 2880°, 3240°, 1080° etc.. What do angles over 360 degrees mean ?

Comment: If you keep turning around you get more degrees out of it. Two rounds give you 720, 10 rounds give you 3600 and so for. You end up at the same point but  you get more degrees. Sort of like the clock hands.